# Issue with redrawing objects in HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, object, canvas

I am using HTML canvas to draw, then move a red square across the screen. However, when I change the x value of the square and redraw it, an error is thrown stating that "mg_player1 is not defined..." I can't seem to figure out the issue in the code, can anyone help?

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
#mg_canvas {
 padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
 width: 1600px;
 height: 800px;
 border: 4px solid black;
}
</style>
<body onload="mg_start()">
<div class="hideMultiGames">
<button class="button" onclick="mg_player1.moveUp()">Click me!</button>
<script>
 function mg_start() {
  multiGames_area.drawCanvas();
  var mg_player1 = new mg_player("red", 0, 670);
 }
 var multiGames_area = {
  canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
  drawCanvas : function() {
   if (document.getElementById("mg_canvas")) {
   }
   else {
    this.canvas.width = 1600;
    this.canvas.height = 800;
    this.canvas.id = "mg_canvas"
    this.canvas.className = "hideMultiGames";
    multiGames_area.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    
   }
  },
  mg_drawGround : function() {
   var mg_ground;
   mg_ground = document.getElementById("mg_canvas");
   var ground = mg_ground.getContext("2d");
   ground.moveTo(0,700);
   ground.lineTo(1600,700);
   ground.stroke();
  },
  mg_clear : function() {
   this.context.clearRect(0, 0, 1600, 800);
  },
 }
 function mg_player(color, x, y) { //stores general shared methods and properties of players
  this.width = 30;
  this.height = 30;
  this.color = color;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  ctx = multiGames_area.context;
  ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  this.moveUp = function() { //function that is throwing errors
   this.x = 1000;
   ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
   ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  };
 }
 
</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: Because you never defined `mg_player1` globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `mg_player1` object globaly. If you use the `var` keyword the object is created only in the current function context.

```
mg_player1 = new mg_player("red", 0, 670);
```

And you need to call `mg_clear` in the `moveUp` function to redraw to canvas. Also better read the `width` and `height` property from the canvas in your `mg_clear` function.

So the script should be like this.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
#mg_canvas {
 padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
 width: 1600px;
 height: 800px;
 border: 4px solid black;
}
</style>
<body onload="mg_start()">
<div class="hideMultiGames">
<button class="button" onclick="mg_player1.moveUp()">Click me!</button>
<script>
 function mg_start() {
  multiGames_area.drawCanvas();
  //define the `mg_player1` object global (in the `window` context)
  mg_player1 = new mg_player("red", 0, 670);
 }
 var multiGames_area = {
  canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
  drawCanvas : function() {
   if (document.getElementById("mg_canvas")) {
   }
   else {
    this.canvas.width = 1600;
    this.canvas.height = 800;
    this.canvas.id = "mg_canvas"
    this.canvas.className = "hideMultiGames";
    multiGames_area.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    
   }
  },
  mg_drawGround : function() {
   var mg_ground;
   mg_ground = document.getElementById("mg_canvas");
   var ground = mg_ground.getContext("2d");
   ground.moveTo(0,700);
   ground.lineTo(1600,700);
   ground.stroke();
  },
  mg_clear : function() {
   //read the width and heigth from the canvas
   this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  },
 }
 function mg_player(color, x, y) { //stores general shared methods and properties of players
        this.width = 30;
  this.height = 30;
  this.color = color;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  ctx = multiGames_area.context;
  ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  this.moveUp = function() {
   //clear the canvas
   multiGames_area.mg_clear();

   this.x = 1000;
   ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
   ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  };
 }
 
</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```